# How do I split a filename using Logstash Grok?

Tags: regex, logstash-grok, grok

One of these days I'll learn regex.

I have the following filename

```
PE-run1000hbgmm3f1-job1000hbgmm3dt-Output-Workflow-1000hbgmm3fb-22.07.17.log
```

I'm able to get this to work so...

```
(?<logtype>[^-]+)-(?<run_id>[^-]+)-(?<job_id>[^-]+)-(?<capability>[^(0-9\.0-9\.0-9)]+)

logtype: PE
run_id: run1000hbgmm3f1
job_id: job1000hbgmm3dt
```

But I'm getting

```
capability: Output-Workflow-
```

...though I want it to be

```
capability: Output-Workflow-1000hbgmm3fb
```

...that is, all the text after the job_id up to the timestamp HH.mm.ss. Any help please? Thanks!

Comment: why not use `[^-]+` for the capability?

Comment: @Chris: Please also consider upvoting the answer if it turned out useful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you cannot negate a *sequence* of symbols with a negated character class. `[^(0-9\.0-9\.0-9)]` matches any single char other than `(`, digit, `.` and `)`.

You may replace your `(?<capability>[^(0-9\.0-9\.0-9)]+)` with `(?<capability>.*?)-\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}` to get the right value.

[image]

Now, the `(?<capability>.*?)-\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}` will match any 0+ chars (and capture them into "capability" group) as few as possible (since the `*?` is a lazy quantifier) up to the *first* occurrence of `-`, followed with 2 digits, and then 3 sequences of a dot (`\.`) followed with 2 digits.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/JdKPTE/1) at regex101.com.